# Screelets - Google Calandar recently stopped working

Tags: screenlets

Ubuntu 14.04/14.10 (and maybe others). The Google Calandar screenlet does not display on the desktop although it still logs in. Does anyone know if this is a Ubuntu problem or a change made by Google and are their any know fixes. If not are there any alternatives other than Conky (an ugly display imo).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Ubuntu Problem. Google switched to API V3. Therefore the screenlet must be fixed. Unfortunately till now there is no fix available.

Alternatives could be eigenCal or eventCal but they are not working on my system (elementaryOS 0.2.1 - based on Ubuntu 12.04).